# Sympa and Postfix: Apache error on list creation

Tags: apache-2.2, postfix, mod-fcgid, sympa

I have setup sympa with postfix. I am having problems with creating lists. Everytime I create a list I get this in my /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
    postalias: fatal: open /etc/aliases.db: Permission denied  
    Failed to execute newaliases: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I tried removing aliases.db and manually using postalias, but alas. The problem doesn't show however when I restart postfix, so I think it is the fast cgi script trying to update the alias files for postfix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to add www-data to the sympa group, and after running postalias on /etc/aliases; chmod the rights of aliases.db to 660. Then chown root:sympa aliases.db.

Answer (score 2):

Ownership of /etc/aliases is usually root:root; this means a normal user cannot update it.

Try removing it and then running postalias with the apache user.

Also check the notes and configuration mentioned in the [manual page for postalias](http://www.postfix.org/postalias.1.html)

Comment: Ok, but to what should I remove it?

Comment: /dev/null ??!!!